# ATM data latitude longitude for country

Tags: google-maps

I was doing some research on ATM locations and I was using Google maps API. Is there a way to get all the ATM locations of a sufficiently large country (like India)? Looking at the API, I was trying to give a max radius of 5000 metres and moving the lat/long by a few degrees each time. Are there better APIs or sites that give this data in an easier way?
Thanks!

Comment: I am sure there must be a good reason for the downvote, but it would help if someone clarified the reason for doing it (so that I can improve the questions in the future)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware about a couple of details regarding the Google Places API web service:

1. Places API doesn't work as a database search, and doesn't return all possible results. It returns only prominent results for a specified area. How Google decides which results are prominent and which are not, I cannot say. There is no any authentic way to get all ATMs from the Places API search.
2. There are certain restrictions in the Terms of Service that prevent such kind of functionality. Have a look at the section 10.4.c(ii) of ToS:

> No creation or augmentation of data sets based on Google’s Content or Services. You will not use Google’s Content or Services to create or augment your own mapping-related dataset (or that of a third party), including a mapping or navigation dataset, business listings database, mailing list, or telemarketing list.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4